# Python 3.x - logging to a single file with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-multiprocessing

I have a Logger class which inherits Thread and there is a TestProcess class which inherits Process. I am trying to use this Logger class in the main process and also TestProcess, however only logs from the main process gets logged.
This issue happens only if I try to use 3.x version. The logging works fine with the 2.7 version

Any idea on what could be the issue here? Sharing the files for reference

Also, I'm using MacOS

```
###########################
# File 1: main.py
###########################
import sys
import time

from logger import log, Logger
from processes import Processes
from test_process import TestProcess
from test_process_2 import TestProcess2


def print_some_text(manager):
    while not manager.exit.is_set():
        log('Inside print_some_text')
        time.sleep(20)
    manager.wait_for_child_processes_to_exit()

def main():
    try:
        logger_thread = Logger("final.log", "test_logs")
        logger_thread.start()

        log("main(): starting")
        processes_manager = Processes(logger_thread)

        test_process_1 = TestProcess('process')
        processes_manager.add_process(test_process_1)
        test_process_1.start()

        test_process_2 = TestProcess2('process')
        processes_manager.add_process(test_process_2)
        test_process_2.start()

        print_some_text(processes_manager)
    except Exception as e:
        log("Error encountered")
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
###########################
# File 2: processes.py
###########################
import signal
from logger import log, stop_logging
from multiprocessing import Event

class Processes:
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.processes = []
        self.exit = Event()
        self.logger = logger
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)

    def add_process(self, proc):
        self.processes.append(proc)

    def exit_gracefully(self, signum, frame):
        log(f"Shutting down processes. Signum: {signum}")
        for p in self.processes:
            p.terminate()
        self.exit.set()

    def wait_for_child_processes_to_exit(self):
        for p in self.processes:
            p.join()
        stop_logging()
        self.logger_thread.join()
```

```
###########################
# File 3: test_process.py
###########################
from multiprocessing import Process, Event

import time
from logger import log

class TestProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self._name = name
        self.exit = Event()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while not self.exit.is_set():
                log("Inside test_process_1")
                time.sleep(10)
        except Exception as e:
            log("Error encountered in test_process_1")

    def terminate(self):
        log("terminate test_process_1")
        self.exit.set()
```

```
###########################
# File 4: test_process_2.py
###########################
from multiprocessing import Process, Event

import time
from logger import log

class TestProcess2(Process):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self._name = name
        self.exit = Event()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while not self.exit.is_set():
                log("Inside test_process_2")
                time.sleep(10)
        except Exception as e:
            log("Error encountered in test_process_2")

    def terminate(self):
        log("terminate test_process_2")
        self.exit.set()
```

```
###########################
# File 5: logger.py
###########################

import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from multiprocessing import Queue
from threading import Thread

LOG_QUEUE = Queue()

class Logger(Thread):
    def __init__(self, logfile, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self._logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(logfile, when="midnight", interval=1, backupCount=0)
        self._logger.addHandler(handler)
        self._syslog_open = False


    def run(self):
        while True:
            record = LOG_QUEUE.get()
            if record is None:
                break
            self._log(record)


    def _log(self, msg):
        self._logger.log(20, msg)

def log(msg):
    if msg is None:
        return
    LOG_QUEUE.put(msg)

def stop_logging():
    LOG_QUEUE.put(None)
```

Comment: There is no multiprocessing in this code

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want your logger to be implemented like this?

Comment: Because it's not the easiest way by far

Comment: you don't need a thread at all, and the `log` method should be in the class. If you want your logging function to be accessible without recreating a logger each time, you can make the logger singleton (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-pattern-in-python-a-complete-guide/)

Comment: @anom907zat - I am trying to use a Queue shared between different Process. So the Logger inherits a thread and keeps reading this Queue until there is an interruption. Different Process can puts into this shared Queue and logger thread will keep writing to the file

Comment: Any reason you're not using the approach recommended in the Python logging docs (cookbook)?

Comment: @VinaySajip - yes, I did go through the Logging Cookbook. Thanks for providing a detailed content. I was looking at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes specifically. Based on the details, I believe I do not have to create a Logger class of type Thread? Is there a way I can configure the logger once and use the same in all the Process?

Comment: That is what the cookbook example does.

Comment: I was trying to follow this approach - "you may want to use a listener thread rather than a separate listener process – the implementation would be analogous". Compared to the example, I believe the main difference is - 
1. queue needs to be created in the main process and pass in the logger_thread
2. in the "worker_process", logger config needs to be provided?

Any reason why the same code works in the 2.7 and not in 3.x versions?